# User trying to join Google Groups is rejected as an existing member when not on the list

Tags: google-groups

I'm an admin for Google Groups list and I'm having a problem where a user is not being allowed to join, with the rejection stating that the person is already a member.

When I look at the members list, she is not there. But she is on the list that have received invitations. I removed her from that list and asked her to resend her subscription request to the list. She then got a rejection email along the lines of:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> `example-news+subscribe@googlegroups.com`
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
> Failed to create an account for user@example.com - EMAIL_EXISTS

I've detailed [the question in Google's forum](http://64.233.169.77/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=159a1c0cc0d48909&hl=en) with full header, but the gist has been quoted here.

Are there any other steps that I can/should take? I've searched in [the Google Groups forums](http://groups.google.com/support/?hl=en) for anything that could help and came up empty.

Or will my issue need the attention of and escalation to a Google employee?

Comment: Has this person unsubscribed at some point after becoming a member initially?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, can they sign up with a different email address, and then once accepted re-configure their account to use the desired email?

Comment: Not really acceptable considering (as it would happen) given the technological sophistication of this user.

Comment: \*shrug\* People tend to stay technologically unsophisticated if they're never given the opportunity to learn things because that thing might be too scary for them.